# How to pass a reference of DOM object to jQuery function?

Tags: jquery, pass-by-reference

I want to pass a reference of the DOM object to a jQuery function. However the function does not get a reference to the DOM object.  It does get a string containing the DOM object. So i get an error on the following example

```
<input type="text" size="30" onchange="change_total_price(this)" id="priceField">
```

.

```
function change_total_price(input) {
    input.closest('div').find('#amountField').val());
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to wrap it, like this:

```
function change_total_price(input) {
  var val = $(input).closest('div').find('#amountField').val();
}
```

`this`, being `input` in the function is a *DOM element*, but [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) is a *jQuery object* method so you need to wrap it in [`$()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) to get a jQuery object if you want to use it.

Alternatively do this outside of your markup, like this:

```
$(function() {
  $("#priceField").change(function() {
    var val = $(this).closest('div').find('#amountField').val();
  });
});
```

This way binds the [`change` event](http://api.jquery.com/change/) handler to the `id="preiceField"` element, you can remove the in-line `onchange="change_total_price(this)"`...it's both cleaner and easier to maintain (can be outside your page in an external `.js` loaded and cached once, for example).

As an aside, IDs should be **unique**, so it doesn't need to be relative at all, both of the above examples can just be:

```
var val = $('#amountField').val();
```